# How to reference calculated column with group by - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I currently have this command:

```
select c.shop, count(*)*c.cost as "Income"
from a
inner join c
on a.courseid = c.courseid
group by c.shop, c.cost
```

Which brings back a table similar to this:

```
SHOP   INCOME
-------------
Shop1  30
Shop2  40
Shop2  25
```

I would want to get a result like:

```
SHOP   INCOME
-------------
Shop1  30
Shop2  65
```

I've tried:

```
select distinct c.STORE, count(*)*c.FEE as Income, sum(Income) as Store_Income
from attendancecheck a
inner join course c
on a.course_id = c.course_id
group by c.STORE, c.FEE, Income
```

But I don't know how to reference the calculated column "Income" - Error: ORA-00904: "INCOME": invalid identifier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
select
  shop,
  sum(income)
from (
  select c.shop, count(*)*c.cost as income
  from a
  inner join c
  on a.courseid = c.courseid
  group by c.shop, c.cost
)
group by shop
```

Answer (score 3):

In order to get the result you want, the following would suffice:

```
SELECT c.shop, SUM(c.cost) AS "Income"
  FROM a INNER JOIN c
    ON a.courseid = c.courseid
 GROUP BY c.shop;
```

**EDIT** I guess I should explain this answer since I got a downvote, and I'll try to do so to the best of my ability. But the query above will give the same results as the accepted answer, and it's considerably simpler.

Suppose you have two shops, `Shop1` and `Shop2`. `Shop1` has *i* costs of 30 while `Shop2` has *j* costs of 40 and *k* costs of 25. The OP's query will return a value of 30 * *i* for `Shop1` and values of 40 * *j* and 25 * *k* for `Shop2`. By summing these results and grouping by the shop, one would get the following results:

```
SHOP   INCOME
----------------
Shop1  30*i
Shop2  40*j+25*k
```

The query I gave will return the same result! Summing costs for `Shop1` will return 30 * *i*, while summing costs for `Shop2` will return 40 * *j* + 25 * *k*. I apologize that I can't give a rigorous proof of its logical equivalence to the accepted answer, but I hope this example will at least be evidence in favor.

Comment: You're right, I think in this case yours is the best answer.

Comment: The question isn't great.  what is table A even doing?